# Converting a string into a controller method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create a generic breadcrumbs method in my application controller to assign the breadcrumbs based on the current controller. If I wanted the breadcrumbs for the index of 'Thing', I would need in the view:

```
<%= breadcrumb :things, things %>
```

And for edit or show:

```
<%= breadcrumb :thing, thing %>
```

Where things is a method in the things controller that returns all things, and thing is a method returning the relevant thing.Both are exposed, and I have in my application layout:

```
<%= breadcrumb crumb, crumb_resource %>
```

And in my application controller:

```
def crumb
  return controller_name.singularize.to_sym if edit_or_show_action
  controller_name.to_sym
end

def crumb_resource
  resource = controller_name
  resource = controller_name.singularize if edit_or_show_action
end

def edit_or_show_action
  action_name == 'edit' || 'show'
end
```

This obviously returns a string for crumb_resource, rather than the call to the controller method. From what I can find I believe it has something to do with send, however

```
controller.send(resource)
```

obviously doesn't work. How can I convert the string that is returned into a controller method call?

Comment: What's the reason you need to call a controller method? In most cases controller methods generate views, or are helper methods that you can access from views. Generally you're not supposed to call one controller from another. So why do you need `controller.send(resource)`?

Comment: Because I don't know another way of converting the resource string into the objects that I"m looking for. If you're accessing objects in the view as I need to I think it's best done through controller calls, however I don't want to hard code each one in individually. That's why I"m trying to convert the 'resource' string into a controller method for the view to call. If I'm approaching it wrong or there's a better way please let me know.

Comment: You might be doing something wrong, but perhaps not. I think you need to edit your answer with a concrete example of what you're expecting. Now we're just talking abstract theory here. Put in something concrete and let's see. Normally resources come from models, not controllers, but perhaps in this case there is a more clever way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [Gretel](https://github.com/lassebunk/gretel), then I think what you might be looking for is this:

```
def crumb_resource
  resource = controller_name
  resource = controller_name.singularize if edit_or_show_action

  self.instance_variable_get("@#{resource}")
end
```

This is assuming you have stored the relevant resource into `@resource_name` during the `edit/show/index` action.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer given as I'm assuming it works for people using instance variables to access models in their view, however in the end this worked for me:

```
breadcrumb crumb, eval(crumb_resource)
```

where eval evaluates the string, basically reverse interpolation which sounds pretty cool.

Comment: If that's the case, then what you were looking for is `self.send(resource)`.